# Is this factory a bad practice?

Tags: dart, factory, repository-pattern

I'm working for a generic CRUD Repository but I have some problems with the serialization of my classes. For solving this issue I have create a factory on my base Entity:

```
const factories = {
  Product: Product.fromJson,
};

abstract class Entity {
  [...]
  factory Entity.fromJson({
    required Type type,
    required Map json,
  }) {
    final factory = factories[type];
    if (factory == null) {
      throw Exception('Type Error: ($type) not found on factories');
    }
    return factory(json: json);
  }

  Map get json => {'id': id};
}
```

And in my repository abraction I just use this factory:

```
abstract class IDioCrudRepository<E extends Entity> extends DioRepository {
  IDioCrudRepository({required super.baseUrl});

  FutureOr<E> get(String id) async {
    final res = await dio.get('$baseUrl/$id');
    return Entity.fromJson(
      type: E,
      json: res.data as Map,
    ) as E;
  }
  [...]
}
```

Dou you know guys if this is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you , at least, to make a Builder class and to move all that code far from Entity. In this manner entity class would not have any responsibility  on how to build itself from a key and a json map.

```
const factories = {
 Product: Product.fromJson,
 };

class EntityBuilder {
 static Entity fromJson({
   required Type type,
   required Map json,
 }) {
    final factory = factories[type];
   if (factory == null) {
      throw Exception('Type Error: ($type) not found on factories');
   }
   return factory(json: json);
  }
 }


 abstract class Entity {
   [...]
   Map get json => {'id': id};
 }


abstract class IDioCrudRepository<E extends Entity> extends DioRepository {
   IDioCrudRepository({required super.baseUrl});

 FutureOr<E> get(String id) async {
   final res = await dio.get('$baseUrl/$id');
   return EntityBuilder.fromJson(
          type: E,
            json: res.data as Map,
          ) as E;
   }
 [...]
}
```